# django upload files (models and forms)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I work on a group project with django. I have a problem with file upload. It is an web app to create, share forms with some additional options (graphs, charts,....). I should mention that i am new to django (total beginner)

**1.models.py**:

```
class Form(TimeStampedModel, TitleSlugDescriptionModel):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    is_final = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_result_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="upload_location", null=True, 
                          blank=True, width_field="width_field",
                          height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="upload location", null=True, 
     blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('form-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

**2. forms.py:**

```
class DocumentUpload(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Form
        field = ["image", "file"]
```

**3.** Certainly, i made a migration, changed main settings (urls, MEDIA_ROOT etc)

**4. views.py THIS IS MY PROBLEM** 
I try to modified existing "create_form(request)" function.
In any tutorials we use "form = form from forms.py", In my project we use "form = model from models.py". How should I modify this this function to complete this upload files.

```
def create_form(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.user
    data = ParseRequest(request.POST)
    parsed_form = data.form()
    parsed_questions = data.questions()


    form = Form(request.FILES, author=user,
                title=parsed_form['title'],
                is_final=parsed_form['is_final'],
                is_public=parsed_form['is_public'],
                is_result_public=parsed_form['is_result_public'],
                description=parsed_form['description'])
    form.save()

    for d in parsed_questions:
        question = Question(request.FILES, form=form, question=d['question'])
        question.save()

        for opt in d['options']:
            option = Option(question=question, option=opt)
            option.save()

return render(request, 'forms/form_form.html', {})
```

**I would appreciate any help, thx**

Comment: 1. What is `ParseRequest`? 2. You don't need to initialize form again

Comment: don't name a model as `Form` it will lead to confusion. You are clearly using some third party library (looks like django extension) I wouldn't recommend embracing them until you get a better understanding of django.

Comment: I agree with @e4c5 and also Here I can think, request.FILES passed two times, so requested files reads in `Form(request.FILES` can't be use anymore in `Question(request.FILES,`

Comment: Thx, but still i need a help. name **Form** is not the best one, but as i said it is a group project ( so i dont decide) and for now my part is to add a files upload . I need to modify only this part of code: 'form =Form(...)' I have to both initialize for example : is_public=parsed_form['is_public'], but using a form not a model and upload file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i needed to use a form from forms.py and add additional field manually.
Thx